# Cannot get .click to select image returned in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Sorry for the long post, but I think its hard to understand what I'm trying to solve without all details.

The below code should return the first image to a pop up box when the user clicks on one of the images displayed via

```
<div class="go" id="container"></div>
```

At the moment, when I mouse over the image and try and select one nothing happens. However if I remove 'img' from the below lines it works, but it selects all images.

```
                    $('.go').css('cursor', 'pointer');
                    $('.go').click(function (e) {
```

I'm guessing there is something wrong with my selector?

---

```
_.each(friends, function (item) {
// using a wrapper so the user can click the pic or the name
var wrapper = $('<div class="wrapper" data-friend-request-id="' + item.friendRequestId + '"></div>');
wrapper.append('<img class="images" src="' + item.imageURL + '" />');
wrapper.append('<div>' + item.username + '</div>');
$('#container').append(wrapper);
});

///SECTION 2 -Click/Select friend image to be captured and used with section 3//////////

// set up event handler
 $('#container').on('click', '.wrapper', function () {
console.log(this);
 var wrapper = $(this);
console.log(wrapper.data('friendRequestId'));
 // remove selected from all wrappers in case one was already selected
$('#container .wrapper').removeClass('selected');
 // mark clicked wrapper as selected
wrapper.addClass('selected');
// save friendRequestId as a global that can be read by other code
window.selectedFriendRequestId = wrapper.data('friendRequestId');
// enabled button
$('#simulateAddBadge').removeAttr('disabled');
});



 //Select badge code- Lets user select badge //////////

 $(document).ready(function () {
 $('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
 $('.go img').click(function (e) {
 $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
$('#modal').reveal({
 animation: 'fade',
animationspeed: 600,
closeonbackgroundclick: true,
 dismissmodalclass: 'close'
  });
return false;
 });
 });


<!---Pop up box with info about the badge and options for user to complete-->
            <div id="modal">
                <div id="heading">
                    Award your friend this badge!?
                </div>

                <div id="content_pb">

                    <div id="badgeselect">
                    </div>


                    <p>This will be text that describes the badge
                        <br>and the reason for awarding it</p>

                    <form action="#" method="get">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="Select friend" id="username" required/>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Add comment" id="email" required/>

                        <br>
                        <br>

                    </form>


                    <a id="send" class="button green close">
                        <img src="images/tick.png">Yes, do it now!</a>

                    <a href="http://kudosoo.com/JQUERYYTEST/dannyboy.html" class="button red close">
                        <img src="images/cross.png">No, Iâm insane!</a>
                    <br>
                    <br>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!---Pop up box stuff ends-->
```

Comment: Would be good if you can get an example up and running in jsfiddle and link to it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that you set up the event handler before you create the `img` elements. So the `$('.go img')` can't find anything to work on.

You have two options: either you do the `.css()` and `.click()` calls when you add the `<img>` (you can then add them directly to the element you just created, no need for a selector), or use delegated handlers: you place them on a parent element, and add the selector in the parameters of the `.on` call, for instance: `$(document).on('click','.go img',function...)`.

See the section **Direct and delegated events** in http://api.jquery.com/on/

Edit: of course for the CSS, you'll need to do that at creation, or better, actually add that to the CSS itself:

```
.go img
{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using the following changes.using jQuery event delegation to trigger the click function on the dynamically generated

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.go img').css('cursor', 'pointer');
$('.go').on('click','img',function (e) {
 $(this).width(100).height(100).appendTo('#badgeselect');
  $('#modal').reveal({
    animation: 'fade',
    animationspeed: 600,
    closeonbackgroundclick: true,
    dismissmodalclass: 'close'
   });
  return false;
});
});
```